# How to swap data stored in 2d array between two processors using some MPI command (or combination commands)?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to implement an All-To-All (i.e. MPI_Allgather) operation on a hyper-cube network using C++.

For example, for n( i.e. number of processors) = 8, I store the initial data as

```
p0: [00, 01, 02, ..., 07]; 
p1: [10, 11, 12, ..., 17],
...
... 
p7: [70, 71, 72, ..., 77].
```

Eventually after running All-To-All, data should become

```
p0: [00, 10, 20, ..., 70], 
P1: [01, 11, 21, ..., 71],
..., 
p7: [07, 17, 27, ..., 77].
```

(In other words, every processor grabs data from everyone else).

I though of the algorithm using some mask and loop that involves the step of swapping data between two processors, e.g., swap last 4 elements of p0 with first 4 elements of p3 (sending last 4 elements of p0 to p3 and sending first 4 elements of p3 to p0 at the same time). using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv cannot achieve this because the receivers' half array will be overwritten before it sends out its data. Could anyone help me with what techniques I could use to do this? I thought about using a intermediate buffer, but still not exactly sure how to write the send and receive MPI code.

Or if someone can tell me any other way to implement All-to-All. I would really appreciate.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All-to-all in MPI is performed by `MPI_ALLTOALL` or `MPI_ALLTOALLV`. The regular calls require two distinct buffers for sending and receiving data. The MPI standard also defines an "in place" option for both operations. In your case this code should do it:

```
double p[8];

MPI_Alltoall(MPI_IN_PLACE, 1, MPI_DOBLE,  // send count and datatype are ignored
             p, 1, MPI_DOUBLE,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Unfortunately some MPI implementations do not support this "in place" mode. One notable example is Open MPI. MPICH2 supports it.

Here is one way to implement it: [MPICH2 alltoall.c](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/mpi/mpich2/branches/release/mpich2-1.5.x/src/mpi/coll/alltoall.c)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think MPI_Alltoall you mentioned is to perform "All-to-all personalized" operation. The operation I asked about was "All-to-all operation" which is actually done by MPI_Allgather. The link "MPICH2 alltoall.c" you sent include implementations of 4 algorithms, which helps. But as beginner in MPI, I'm trying understanding how they exchange the data on two processors.

Comment: No, `MPI_ALLGATHER` performs a gather to all processes. It is like performing a regular gather into some root process and then broadcasting the result - all processes get the same result in the end (obviously not your case). With `MPI_ALLTOALL` each rank scatters its buffer to all other ranks while performing gather of the received pieces from the other ranks. Read very carefully [this section](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node101.htm#Node101) of the MPI 2.2 Standard in order to understand what `MPI_ALLTOALL(V)` does.

Comment: After thinking and looking at the docutment carefully, I think you are right. @HristoLLiev Thanks for your correction and help! I appreciate.